# How to Manage Teams in Community Edition of SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

SugarCRM version: 6.2 (Community Edition)

Are there any free plugins (SecuritySuite is not free) available to manage teams in SugarCRM?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[SuiteCRM](http://suitecrm.com/) comes with a free version of teams. It's pretty easy to transition from 6.2 CE to SuiteCRM as SuiteCRM is based on CE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am afraid I can not switch to SuiteCRM.

Comment: Then I would advise using SecuritySuite. It's well supported and well tested. It's one of the few add-ons out there that still supports 6.2.